# Error with valid url using Source.fromUrl

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get a response from a URL using `Source.fromURL`. I generate the URLs from data from a file (in UTF-8). One of the generated URL contains accent (*[https://ow-api.com/v1/stats/pc/EU/Aojhürlkue-2299/profile](https://ow-api.com/v1/stats/pc/EU/Aojh%C3%BCrlkue-2299/profile)*).

Doing a request using the `httpie` command-line tool or using my browser give me the right response but when I do the request from the scala code (using `Source.fromURL`) I have an HTTP error 400.

```
http 'https://ow-api.com/v1/stats/pc/EU/Aojhürlkue-2299/profile'                                                                      
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
...
```

I'm using this code to do the request:

```
def get(url: String) = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url)("utf-8").mkString

val teams = Util.get_teams.map { case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_.btag) ) }
  .toArray
for((team, btags) <- teams) {
  for(name <- btags) {
    try {
      Util.get(s"https://ow-api.com/v1/stats/pc/EU/$name/profile")
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => println(s"$name -> $e")
    }
  }
}
```

and I get this exception:

```
Aojhürlkue-2299 -> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://ow-api.com/v1/stats/pc/EU/Aojhürlkue-2299/profile
```

I'm getting the data from an UTF-8 file:

```
$ file -i all-team.csv
all-team.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Why do I get this error from a valid URL (I get the right response from other tools)?

---

**EDIT**

Here's the code where I read the file:

```
def get_teams() =
  CSVReader.open("all-team.csv", "UTF-8")
    .all()
    .map(a =>
      TeamPlayer(a(0).replace('#', '-'),
                 a(1),
                 if(a(3) == "DPS") { "damage" } else { a(3).toLowerCase } ))
    .groupBy(_.team)
    .map{case (k, v) =>
      (k, v.map{ case TeamPlayer(btag, _, role) => Player(role, btag) })}
```

Comment: `HTTP response code: 400` means the request is invalid

Comment: Other tools that do the exact same request are answered by a code 200. That's why I don't know what's the issue is. If `httpie` and firefox would give me a 400, I would know that it's just my request that is bad but since they accept my request and give me the expected response, I don't know what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying Java classes do not automatically encode the umlaut character.

Use the `java.net.URI` class to do that:

```
Source.fromURL(URI.create(url).toASCIIString)
```

---

BTW, all the other tools you used simply cheat. They show you the `ü` in the HTTP request, but in reality, the encoded to `%C3%BC` when sending.